# None gradients from GradientTape inside a batch training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, collaborative-filtering

I am new to TensorFlow and i'm trying to implement simple collaborative filtering in v2. I have no trouble training on the whole train set at once, but I have problems when I try to batch train. Specifically when calculating `grads` the output gradients are `[None, None]`. The colab file with the full attempt can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Rdi0a0O-6BO84fKbuBLcGIsuw-M-N0UQ?authuser=1#scrollTo=SwHy5I3xnTJ_).

```py
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(user_embedding)
            tape.watch(item_embedding)

            ## Compute the predicted ratings
            predicted_ratings = tf.reduce_sum(user_batch * item_batch, axis=1)

            ## Compute loss
            true_ratings = tf.cast(train_batch_st.values, tf.float32)
            loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(true_ratings, predicted_ratings) # batch loss
            # Cumulative epoch loss (across all batches)
            epoch_loss += loss

            ## Compute gradients of loss with respect to user and item embeddings
            grads = tape.gradient(loss, [user_embedding, item_embedding])
            print(grads) # grads None, None thus causing error below

            # Apply gradients
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [user_embedding, item_embedding]))
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me: just do the `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` within the gradient tape.

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    user_batch = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(user_embedding, user_ids) # shape = batch_size x embedding_dims
    item_batch = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(item_embedding, item_ids) # shape = batch_size x embedding_dims

    ## Compute the predicted ratings
    true_ratings = tf.cast(train_batch_st.values, tf.float32)
    predicted_ratings = tf.reduce_sum(user_batch * item_batch, axis=1)

    ## Compute loss
    # Using MSE here
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(true_ratings, predicted_ratings) # batch loss

# Cumulative epoch loss (across all batches)
epoch_loss += loss

## Compute gradients of loss with respect to user and item embeddings
grads = tape.gradient(loss, [user_embedding, item_embedding])

# Apply gradients (update user and item embeddings)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [user_embedding, item_embedding]))
```